# Table name not mapped to camel case by Mybatis Generator

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I tried Mybatis Generator and it worked very well. However, even though the column names were mapped correctly to camel case, the file names (Mapper.xml, Client and Model) didn't follow camel case.

So, for example, table TIPO_SERVICO was mapped to Tiposervico/TiposervicoMapper instead of TipoServico/TipoServicoMapper.

I checked Mybatis Generator docs and didn't find a property related to table name case.

P.s. My DB is Oracle.

My generatorConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC
        "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd" >
<generatorConfiguration>
    <context id="context" targetRuntime="MyBatis3Simple">
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true"/>
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection userId="[USER]" password="[PASSWORD]" driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[IP]:1521:[ENV]">
            <property name="remarksReporting" value="true"/>
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaTypeResolver>
            <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="false"/>
        </javaTypeResolver>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.model" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false"/>
            <property name="trimStrings" value="true"/>
        </javaModelGenerator>

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.mapper" targetProject="src/main/resources/META-INF">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false"/>
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="com.mapper" type="XMLMAPPER" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false"/>
        </javaClientGenerator>

        <table schema="patr" tableName="%" enableCountByExample="true" enableDeleteByExample="false"
               enableSelectByExample="true" enableUpdateByExample="false" >
            <domainObjectRenamingRule searchString="^Scm" replaceString="" />
        </table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel case naming worked again after commenting the domainObjectRenamingRule.

Answer (score 1):

Why not configure it manually? add attribute of **domainObjectName**

```
    <table schema="patr" tableName="TIPO_SERVICO" domainObjectName ="TipoServico" enableCountByExample="true" enableDeleteByExample="false"
           enableSelectByExample="true" enableUpdateByExample="false" >
        <domainObjectRenamingRule searchString="^Scm" replaceString="" />
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't use domainObjectName because I use it to generate code for dozens of tables. However, after I commented the domainObjectRenamingRule, camel case naming started to work again.